# Object doesn't support this property or method in my HTA App

Tags: vbscript, hta

```
Sub UserID
    Dim objNetwork
    objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network") 'This is where I get the message
    Dim struserid
    struserid = objNetwork.UserName
    If Len(Trim(struserid)) = 0 or struserid = "*" Then 
        MsgBox "Please enter a valid username.",48,"Invalid entry"
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

I used this code in another sub routine of my app and it works fine.

However when I use this in this subroutine, I got this error:

> Object doesn't support this property or method.

Comment: `Set objNetwork = ...` 8-)

Comment: I had Set there before and I removed it to debug. It was happening with Set too

Comment: Try `MsgBox TypeName(CreateObject("WScript.Network"))` instead, what is the output?

Comment: If it was happening with `Set` *(which I doubt)* why accept the answer that regurgitates that assumption?

Comment: I checked my code and you were right. I forgot to put a space between Set and objNetwork

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When assigning objects to variables you must use the [`Set`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4afksd44%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) keyword:

```
Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
```

Comment: Surely this has been answered before?